# Is it possible to get Elementor Style of post content in $post->post_content?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, elementor

**What I am trying to get?**
I'm creating an Elementor custom widget. which will output a list of posts of a specific post type.  Thus far everything is ok. I'm getting all I need. But the issue is, I have to output post content with its Elementor customization(created with Elementor). I've used **WP_Query** and **get_posts()**. all I get is raw HTML without any Elementor customization classes . Please check the image
[image: This is the issue]

**What I've done?**

```
public function wp_post_list($slug_name,$order='ASC',$orderby='date'){
        $args = [
                'post_type' => $slug_name,
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'          => $orderby,
                'order'            => $order,
            ];
            return $all_posts = new \WP_Query($args);
    }
public function post_list($slug_name,$order='ASC',$orderby='date'){
            $args = [
                    'post_type' => $slug_name,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby'          => $orderby,
                    'order'            => $order,
                ];
            $all_posts = get_posts($args);
            return $all_posts;
    }

public function skin_time_line($slug){

        $st = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        $order = $st['post_order'];
        $orderby = $st['post_orderby'];
        $posts = $this->post_list($slug,$order,$orderby);
        $all_posts = $this->wp_post_list($slug,$order,$orderby);  
   
        echo '<div class="time_line">';

         foreach($posts as $post){
           echo '<div class="time_line_post">';

             echo '<div class="tl_content">'.$post->post_content.'</div>';
              //Getting just the HTML without any class

           echo '</div>';
         }
        echo '</div>';

//or With WP_Query

        echo '<div class="content">';
        $all_posts = $this->wp_post_list($slug,$order,$orderby);
                if ($all_posts->have_posts()) : 
                    while ($all_posts->have_posts()) : $all_posts->the_post();
                            the_content(); // Getting just the HTML without any class
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

}
```

Please help! Any kind of suggestion or documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use

```php
echo Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display(get_the_ID());
```

> Used to render and return the post content with all the Elementor elements.

https://github.com/elementor/elementor/blob/9aadba35a9ad52cd5e9cbef55a5761f47403491c/includes/frontend.php#L1020-L1025

if you want only the content you can use

```php
echo Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: Do you know how to make JS scripts work? I embeded to the widget render() function some JS script and it does not work. even a simple script: `<script>var val="some value"; </script>`.